# How does the pre-processor work in the following example?

Tags: c

In the following example:

```
#define PRNT(x, y) printf("X is %s and Y is %s\n", #x, #y)
int main(void)
{
    PRNT("HELLO", 4);
}
```

This gives:

> X is "HELLO" and Y is 4

How does the pre-processor do substitution in the above? For example, why wouldn't it evaluate to:

1. Start: `printf("X is %s and Y is %s\n", #x, #y)`
2. Add in x="Hello", y=4: `printf("X is %s and Y is %s\n", "Hello", 4)`
3. Printf should return: `X is Hello and Y is 4\n` <-- `HELLO` not `"HELLO"`

So then how/why does it add in the additional `"` around HELLO; that is, why does it print `..."HELLO"...` instead of just `...HELLO...` ? Does the preprocessor translate the quotes in a string into `\"` so it ends up becoming `\"HELLO\"` and `"4"` when passing those two args to the `printf` function?

Comment: @tadman do all compilers have that or just GCC? (I'm obviously currently using GCC)

Comment: It's been around a long time, but I think the implementations in other compilers differ in subtle ways when it comes to *how* things are stringified and what sort of things you can operate on.

Comment: Worth noting that in what you expected your code to look like after preprocessing, you have the integer literal 4 as an argument, but its associated format specifying is `%s`, so you still would not have seen the results printed that you expected.

Comment: The code is wrong. It does not evaluate macros passed as arguments to PRNT. It needs one additional level of indirection. `#define STRINGIFY(x) #x`, `#define PRNT(x, y) printf("X is %s and Y is %s\n", STRINGIFY(x), STRINGIFY(y))`. Imagine: `#define FOUR 4`, `PRNT(FOUR, FOUR+1)` -> `X is FOUR and Y is FOUR+1`. arrgh!

Comment: @pqans could you please clarify what you mean? What is indirection when applied to a macro?

Comment: Either you pass literals to the `PRNT` macros, then the stringification works as expected but you have hardcoded values, which is bad. Or you pass symbolic values, then you avoid hardcoded values but the stringification strigifies the parameter name instead of the value which is unintended. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#SEC17. _If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros. [...]_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does the preprocessor translate the quotes in a string into `\"` so it ends up becoming `\"HELLO\"` and `"4"` when passing those two args to the
> printf function?*

Yes.

If you're happy to accept Microsoft documentation, then [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/stringizing-operator-hash?view=msvc-160):

> Further, if a character contained in the argument usually requires an
> escape sequence when used in a string literal, for example, the
> quotation mark (") or backslash (\) character, the necessary escape
> backslash is automatically inserted before the character.

Or, if you'd prefer a more official version, here's what this [C11 (Draft) Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says:

> ### 6.10.3.2 The # operator
>
> …
>
> #### 2 Semantics
>
> …   Otherwise, the original spelling of each preprocessing token in the argument
> is retained in the character string literal, except for special handling for producing the
> spelling of string literals and character constants: a \ character is inserted before each " and \ character of a character
> constant or string literal (including the delimiting " characters),
> …

Answer (score 3):

That would be true with `x, y` but not `#x, #y` which employs the ["stringizing" modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html).

If you stringize a string you just get a string, but it'll contain the surrounding quotes. If you stringize a number you get a string.

In general for a given `x` you'll get `"x"`, so for `"x"` you get `"\"x\""`.

Answer (score 2):

`#X` gives a string literal whose content is X.  So `#` with argument `"FOO"` gives a string literal whose five characters are `"`, `F`, `O`, `O`, `"` .  (And null terminator of course)

Preprocessing happens after the code has been tokenized and escape sequences processed , and the result of preprocessing is a token stream  (not some kind of source file that needs re-tokenization and re-escape-processing).

Answer (score 2):

`"HELLO"` is the token you are passing into your macro.  The `#` operator turns that into a string, so your string will be "\"HELLO\"", much like when you pass the number `4` in, it becomes `"4"`.  So when the Preprocessor runs, I would expect your code to look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("X is %s and Y is %s\n", "\"HELLO\"", "4");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is doing this because of the '#' in front of the variables inside the macro. It is called the "stringification" operator, and it will take the input variable and, well, stringify it. That means placing quotation marks around it, as well as escaping ones already in the variable. This means, when expanded, `"Hello"` becomes `"\"Hello\""` and `4` becomes `"4"`.

Answer (score 1):

Stringizing (what happens when you do something like `#x` in your macro) takes the item and turns it into a string. In the case of `4`, you get `"4"`, in the case of `"HELLO"`, you get `"\"HELLO\""`, because both of those are the exact string you would need to reproduce the item when printing it, for example.

Many compilers have an option to stop after pre-processing to allow you to examine its effects, such as with the `-E` flag of `gcc`:

```
pax:~> gcc --std=c17 -E prog.c
# 1 "prog.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "prog.c"

int main(void)
{
    printf("X is %s and Y is %s\n", "\"HELLO\"", "4");
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's very helpful using the `-E`. Could you please explain what the first 7 lines are -- the ones with the `#` before it?

Answer (score 0):

The `#x` converts `x` to a string.

i.e.

```
x = "Hello"
```

Then

```
#x = "\"Hello\""
```